# Why SatisfyImportsOnce method doesn't work with the object parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been following this MSDN example about the `CompositionContainer` class (`System.ComponentModel.CompositionHosting`):

```
[Export]
class MyAddin
{
    public String myData { get { return "The data!"; } }
}

class MyProgram
{
    [Import]
    public MyAddin myAddin { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AggregateCatalog catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MyAddin).Assembly));
        CompositionContainer _container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        MyProgram myProgram = new MyProgram();
        _container.SatisfyImportsOnce(myProgram);
        Console.WriteLine(myProgram.myAddin.myData);
        Console.ReadLine();

        _container.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But when I try to compile it, this error message is generated:

> Error 2   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.SatisfyImportsOnce(System.ComponentModel.Composition.Primitives.ComposablePart)'
>   has some invalid
>   arguments X:\Dev\S-L\CSharp\EtceteraSolution\CompositionContainer_Demo\CompositionContainer_Main.cs   15  13  CompositionContainer_Demo

[image: Invalid arguments for <code>SatisfyImportsOnce</code> method.]

Sample source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It's better to provide both errors in the text format and point out the line where it complains instead of uploading an image that will likely disappear in a month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing extension method that can do it. You just need to add correct `using` on top of your program. I guess the example doesn't show the necessary `usings`.

The method you're looking for is: [public static ComposablePart SatisfyImportsOnce(this ICompositionService compositionService, object attributedPart);](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd779466(v=vs.110).aspx)

Add `using System.ComponentModel.Composition` on your program, and the extension method should work fine.

Alternatively, it's also possible to call extensionmethod like this:

`AttributedModelServices.SatisfyImportsOnce(_container, myProgram);`

Note, it's in .NET framework >= 4.0.